# QT gui items won't shrink to ft to their parent widget

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I have three widgets under my main window . I design my program that each widget will be controlled by a class .

Last 2 hours I waste my time to fit 3 GUI elements to one of this widgets. 
I want to have a label and a line item and a button. I put them in to a grid layout(in real case I have 3 row for simplicity I put 1 row in the example below). And set the grid layout's parent to my class.
What I expect is this GUI items to resize themselves and fit to one row in this widget,  no matter what I tried I couldn't succeed .

In short I expect this items to shrink to fit to the widget by themselves. But couldn't figure out how to do it. Any advice ?

```
void
enviromentSetup::createDialogs()
{
    numberOfPoints  = new QLabel (QApplication::translate("leftPanel","numberOfPoints"));

    inputNumberOfPoints = new       
    QLineEdit(QString::number(st_environmentParamaters.number_of_points_in_line));

    maxElementsButton = new QPushButton("Max Elems");

    gridLayout = new QGridLayout(this);
    gridLayout->addWidget(numberOfPoints, 0, 0);
    gridLayout->addWidget(inputNumberOfPoints, 0, 1);
    gridLayout->addWidget(maxElementsButton, 0, 2);


    this->show();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I deleted my answer because I hadn't seen you're using another constructor of QGridLayout, wich recieves the parent widget. But this raises another question that your code doesn't show: What kind of class is environmentSetup? Does it inherit from QWidget, QDialog?

Comment: No worries , thanks for reply . EnvironmentSetup inherents QWidget.

Comment: You should not set a parent on the layout, itself! Also, I do not see the layout setting code in this snippet. Please paste more code.

Comment: Does calling setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Ignored, QSizePolicy::Ignored) on each of your three widgets get you the behavior you want?

Answer (score 0):

It is insufficient to merely make the parent of the layout the main widget. You also have to explicitly set the layout of the widget.

Add the following line just before you show the widget:

```
this->setLayout(gridLayout);
```